# Using Nested macros in C

Tags: c

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<stdio.h>

#define PR(x) printf("%d\t",(int)(x));
#define PRINT(a,b,c) PR(a) PR(b) PR(c)
#define MAX(a,b) (a<b?b:a)

int main()
{
    int x=1,y=2;
    //PR(MAX(x++,y));
    PRINT(MAX(x++,y),x,y);  //2,2,2
    PRINT(MAX(x++,y),x,y);  //2,3,2
    return 0;
}
```

`x` is 1 so the 3 values to be passed as arguments in PRINT is 2 2 2.

Then in the second PRINT the values that will be passed is 2 3 2. So the output should be 2 2 2 2 3 2. But this program outputs as 2 2 2 3 4 2.

Comment: Undefined behavior. There was a question almost exactly like it, though formulated in a slightly different way, not 1 hour ago... EDIT: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056315/c-printf-operation)

Comment: Sorry I was too quick. It's that other common macro error: evaluating arguments multiple times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `MAX` macro is bad. It evaluates one of its arguments twice.

```
 MAX(x++,y)
```

expands to:

```
 (x++ < y ? y : x++)
                ^^^
```

So `x` is incremented twice if it started out smaller than `y`.

There is no undefined behavior in that code because there is a [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) between the evaluation of the first part of the ternary operator and the part that is selected. The whole `PRINT` expression expands to:

```
 printf("%d\t", (x++ < y ? y : x++));
 printf("%d\t", (x));
 printf("%d\t", (y));
```

Which is all fine. This *does not* mean you should be using such macros. Use simple functions, and let the compiler do its job of type-checking and inlining what it thinks is best.

Answer (score 5):

Your macros have several problems:

- Never hide a `;` inside a macro but have it behave like an ordinary
  statement
- Don't write macros that evaluate their arguments multiple times
- always put parentheses around macro parameters such that you know the
  precedence of all operators.

Answer (score 3):

Your `MAX(x++,y)` call translates to `(x++<y?y:x++)` and results in double modification of `x` during the first call.

Comment: This isn't undefined behaviour.  There is a sequence point after the `?`.

Answer (score 1):

PRINT((MAX(x++,y),x,y) -> PR(MAX(x++,y)) PR(x) PR(y) -> PR(x++

x = 1, y = 2
Does PR(2 since 1<2) and increments x to 2
Then PR(2) PR(2) - Hence output 2 2 2

Next PR(MAX(x++ (i.e.2) < 2 - false) ? 2 : x++ (i.e use incremented value of x from condition (3) then output 3 and increment x to 4) - hence x gets incremented twice